# Need to put a scrollable Div inside a container with relative position and scrollable should not affect the main div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

[image: Open Menu Image][image: Closed Menu Image]

Above you can see. I have two divs. one is fixed and second is scrollable. The right sided div can be expanded and collapsed and the second div will adjust its width accordingly.

Now I want to place a div whose size and positioning should be not affected by the right side div's state ( either open or closed ) and I want to make it scrollable. Adding position absolute add scrolls to whole page and the fixed Div on right is not of 100% height anymore. Can someone draw a basic code structure using flexbox on how to create such flow.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of way to do that, but lets propose one that mix positionning (for the header) and usage of flex box (for the side panel and the main area)

First a basic html structure

```
<div class='app'>
  <div class='app-header'>header content</div>
  <div class='app-content'>
    <div class='side-panel'>panel content</div>
    <div class='main-area'>area content</div>
  </div>
<div class='app>
```

then some less/css

```
.app {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.app-header {
  background: yellow;
}
.app-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
 }
.side-panel {
  height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: blue;
}
.main-area {
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  background: green;
}
```

see it on JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/70qxu4L3/

Comment: main issue with sort of approach is the content inside left div and header. I am making these div grow and shrink based on the content inside them. If I put a fixed value even in view port or %. it doesnt look good with every device. so thats why I need to keep them flexible according the content. If you can suggest another approach for the content inside ( this can work for me

Comment: just remove the width and height on those :) - oh and use the flex box for the header too since my example was showing two different approach - I edited answer + jsfiddle

Comment: tweaked a bit according my needs but it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this css code :D

```
body {
    position: relative;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    height: header height; // put header height
    top: 0;
}

fixedLeftDiv {
    position: fixed;
    top: header height;
    left: 0;
}

scrollableDiv {
    position: fixed or absolute; // choose what you need
    top: header height; 
    left: fixedLeftDiv width;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is one issue with this position fixed approach. I need to know the height of my header everytime. which I dont. Because the content inside the side div and header is responsive and these divs grow  and shrink according to them. If I keep a fixed height even in % or viewport. it looks bad on some devices and good on the other based on their view size